# Prevent duplicate inserton of element int the dom in jquery

Tags: jquery

Please help me out! I have a textarea that counts and displays the number of text user enters but as the text increases or decreases the counter element creates duplicates on the dom. I want it to display one element but the counter number to change. Please help me. My jquery code is below.

```
//on type show text remain on textarea inout fields
$('textarea').on("input", function(){
    var maxlength = $(this).attr("maxlength");
    var currentLength = $(this).val().length;

    var $txtremain = maxlength - currentLength;

    if( currentLength >= maxlength ){
        console.log("You have reached the maximum number of characters.");
    }else{
      if ($('.txtacntr').length === 0) {
        $(this).after('<span class="txtacntr">' + $txtremain + ' chars left. </span>');
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put div with a span and then change number inside.

You condition was not good "===" changed by "<=".

```js
//on type show text remain on textarea inout fields
$(".counter span").text($('textarea').attr("maxlength"));

$('textarea').on("input", function(){
    var maxlength = $(this).attr("maxlength");
    var currentLength = $(this).val().length;
   
    var $txtremain = maxlength - currentLength;
    //console.log(maxlength);
    //console.log(currentLength);

    if (currentLength === maxlength) {
      $(".counter span").text('0');
    } else if ($('.txtacntr').length <= maxlength) {
      $(".counter span").text($txtremain);
    } else if( currentLength >= maxlength ){
        console.log("You have reached the maximum number of characters.");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea maxlength="60"></textarea>
<div class="counter"><span></span> chars left.</div>
```

Comment: `$('.txtacntr').length < maxlength` doesn't make any sense

Comment: Thanks bro, but i just tested it and it's not working.

Comment: Thanks alot The_Death_Raw, your answer worked for me. I just had to make a few changes.

Answer (score 0):

This finally works for me.

```
$('textarea').on("input", function(){
    var maxlength = $(this).attr("maxlength");
    var currentLength = $(this).val().length;

    var $txtremain = maxlength - currentLength;

    if (currentLength === maxlength) {
      $(".counter span").text('0');
    } else if ( currentLength <= maxlength) {
      $(".counter span").text($txtremain);
    }
});
```